# Términos anteriores para la suma en español

Tags: historia, sinónimos, matemáticas, español-medio

Leyendo acerca del *Sumario Compendioso*, que es el primer libro de matemática escrito en América en 1556, veía uno de sus problemas que iniciaba así:

> Dame un numero que ajustandole 8, sea quadrado y restando el 8, quede quadrado... *(sic)*

(Puede verse en la segunda página de [este](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/299447121_LOS_PROBLEMAS_DIOFANTICOS_EN_EL_SUMARIO_COMPENDIOSO_DEL_HERMANO_JUAN_DIEZ) pdf)

En español actual sería algo como

> ¿A qué número se le puede sumar o restar 8 obteniendo como resultado un cuadrado entero?

La duda viene del uso del verbo *[ajustar](https://dle.rae.es/ajustar)* como sinónimo de sumar, algo que hoy no se usa (al menos no de forma habitual). En el mapa de diccionarios ya el verbo *sumar* aparece con significado aritmético en 1780, al igual que el sustantivo *adición*, pero ni el sustantivo *ajuste* ni el verbo *ajustar* tienen significado aritmético. ¿Hasta qué época se usó esta palabra como sinónimo de suma? ¿Qué otras palabras se utilizaban para designar la adición hacia la época del libro (mediados del siglo XVI)?

Comment: En el Quijote, Cervantes usa "montan" y "hecen" para decir "suman": https://books.google.es/books?id=OkE5aSwMyJUC&pg=PT481&lpg=PT481&dq=%22que+hacen+setecientos+y+cincuenta+reales%22&source=bl&ots=PPv9xROQO4&sig=ACfU3U2QKLugwmHjZtJMjyiM19HLAoGPlA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjItrO3q8_nAhVSTBoKHUbsBFoQ6AEwAXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22que%20hacen%20setecientos%20y%20cincuenta%20reales%22&f=false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según se explica en el artículo ["Las cuatro reglas: aproximación al léxico de las aritméticas prácticas del Renacimiento"](http://www.cervantesvirtual.com/descargaPdf/las-cuatro-reglas--aproximacin-al-lxico-de-las-aritmticas-prcticas-del-renacimiento-0/), de Mª Jesús Mancho Duque (Universidad de Salamanca), en esa época se usaban "sumar" y "suma", con frecuencia escritos en las formas latinizantes "summar" y "summa". "Addición" también se utilizaba, pero parece ser que mucho menos:

> El cultismo *sumar*, documentado, según el DCECH, en Nebrija, aparece desde los primeros textos matemáticos, si bien su representación gráfica puede ser más latinizante, lo que corrobora el nivel de 
>   obras de álgebra o el texto de Pérez de Moya, de 1562, frente al de 1589, más divulgativo:
>
> > (7) *En exemplo de sumar todas las tres sumas sobredichas en uno* (Ortega, 1512: 5r). 
> >     
> >     *Muchos y quasi todos los que han escrito d'esta regla han hecho división y differencia en el summar d'ella*
> >     (Aurel, 1552: 36r). 
> >     
> >     *El primero tracta las quatro reglas generales de Arithmética, conviene saber: summar, restar, multiplicar, 
> >     partir por números enteros, cosa muy necessaria para el servicio de la vida humana y digna de ser sabida de 
> >     todo hombre que desseare ser puesto en el número de los que sienten d'esta razón* (Pérez de Moya, 1562: X). 
> >     *Sumar es juntar muchos números o partidas en una* (Pérez de Moya, 1589: 14v). 
> >     
> >     *Si queremos summar estas dos raízes, scilicet, raíz de 7 y raíz de 5, diremos que la summa d'ellas es raíz 
> >     ligada de 7 más raíz de 5, que es modo claro y que satisfaze* (Núñez, 1567: 52r).
>
> Aparecen frecuentes compuestos sintagmáticos, como *suma mayor*, contrapuesto a *suma menor*:
>
> > (8) *Mas es de notar que si el quebrado de la summa mayor (de la qual se resta la menor) fuesse de menor valor que el quebrado que ha de ser restado, digo que en tal caso ay necessidad que el quebrado menor tome 
> >     algún socorro de su entero* (Pérez de Moya, 1562: 181). 
> >     
> >     *Y sabe que los quadrados de las dos partes no pueden hazer summa tan grande como es el quadrado de todo 
> >     el número que queremos partir, ny pueden hazer summa menor que la mitad del quadrado del mismo número* (Núñez, 1567: 175v).
>
> Lo que sólo hemos encontrado en dos testimonios presentes en el Índice de la obra de Núñez Salaciense es *addición*, que en sentido matemático el *Diccionario Histórico* (s.v. *adición*) documenta a partir del 
>   XVII:
>
> > (9) *Juntar con estos 2 números, 3 y 2, otros dos números, en la proporción de 5 para 1, y que sean tales que, 
> >     hecha esta addición, resulte el uno duplo del otro* (Núñez, 1567: VIIr). 
> >     
> >     *Tenemos estos dos números, 8 y 12, y juntando con el 8 un número ignoto y juntando con el 12 la octava 
> >     parte del mismo número ignoto, resultan yguales el 8 y el 12, hecha la tal addición, y queremos conoscer el ignoto* (Núñez, 1567: VIIIr).

De hecho, en Google Libros se encuentra el [*Libro primero de arithmetica algebraica*](https://books.google.es/books?id=2qrrCWJQX2cC&q=summa&hl=it&source=gbs_word_cloud_r&cad=5#v=snippet&q=summar&f=false) de Marco Aurel, publicado en 1552, en el cual podemos ver muchos ejemplos de uso de "summar" y "summa".

En los textos citados observamos que a veces se usa también "juntar" para indicar "sumar". "Ajuntar" es una forma arcaica equivalente a "juntar" (todavía se usa hoy en día de forma popular). Aparece de hecho  en el [*Léxico Hispanoamericano del siglo XVI*](https://books.google.es/books?id=rGmU7O8ljkUC&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=ajuntar+%22siglo+XVI%22&source=bl&ots=jfc_39EXed&sig=ACfU3U3kbNAlZrAjIrOc2KglaBVyHQ0KVQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0n8-Yu9jnAhVF8OAKHVQzATMQ6AEwAHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=ajuntar%20%22siglo%20XVI%22&f=false). Además, podemos ver como [Jerónimo Cortés](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jer%C3%B3nimo_Cort%C3%A9s) utilizaba "ajuntar" en contextos aritméticos, en frases muy parecidas a las de la pregunta, en su libro [*Arithmetica practica*](https://books.google.es/books?id=OMhZAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA497&lpg=PA497&dq=%22numero+que+ajuntandole%22&source=bl&ots=4fplB282ex&sig=ACfU3U0poAkZ5Xm2V8VbswP_iA27mHXqGw&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwicxtP7tNbnAhWhz4UKHVgFCYoQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22numero%20que%20ajuntandole%22&f=false). Por ejemplo,

> Dame un numero que ajuntandole 11 haga 27.

Observando la imagen de Google Libros del enlace anterior, podéis ver otros ejemplos de este estilo.

Respecto al uso de "ajustar" en el *Sumario Compendioso*, inicialmente pensé que podría tratarse de una peculiar deformación de "ajuntar". La Universidad de Salamanca ha creado un [Diccionario de la Ciencia y de la Técnica del Renacimiento](http://dicter.usal.es/) en el cual podemos encontrar una serie de sinónimos de ["sumar" o "summar"](http://dicter.usal.es/?palabra=sumar&tipo=0) usados en la época:

> añadir, ayuntar, juntar, montar, hacer

Y, si buscamos ["juntar"](http://dicter.usal.es/?palabra=juntar&tipo=0), podemos encontrar las variantes y sinónimos

> junctar, juntar, yuntar, ajuntar, ayuntar

además de los sinónimos de "sumar" (o "summar") ya mencionados. Por contra, la búsqueda de ["ajustar"](http://dicter.usal.es/?palabra=ajustar&tipo=0) no da ninguna acepción que corresponda al significado de "sumar" y eso me llevó a pensar que "ajustar" no fuese un sinónimo habitual de "sumar".

Pero en la imagen enlazada en la pregunta se ve claramente que se usa "ajustar" tres veces y, además, pude constatar como en una misma página del *Sumario compendioso* se usan tanto "ajustar" como "ayuntar" para indicar "sumar", como se puede ver en una de las imágenes (figura 4) del artículo  ["El primer texto matemático de América"](https://www.revistaciencia.amc.edu.mx/images/revista/59_4/PDF/10-1erTxtMatematico.pdf), de Marco Arturo Moreno Corral. Por lo tanto, no parece que se trate de un simple error de imprenta.

Finalmente, conseguí encontrar indicios que contradecían mi hipótesis inicial: en el libro *Suma de la art de Arismetica* (en catalán) de [Francesc Santcliment](http://dbe.rah.es/biografias/18047/francesc-santcliment), escrito también Francesch Sanct Climent, 
se utiliza "aiustar" muchas veces en el contexto de la suma de números. Se trata de el primer libro de matemáticas impreso en la Península Ibérica, en 1482. La copia original que se conserva en la actualidad se encuentra en la Biblioteca de Catalunya, pero existe una edición facsímil en el libro *Summa de l'Art d'Aritmètica* con una introducción, notas y transcripción (en catalán) de Antoni Malet (Eumo Editorial, 1998).

Los historiadores Jacques Sesiano y Guy Beaujouan han estudiado las similitudes y relaciones de la obra de Santcliment con una serie de obras de obras de aritmética de la misma época originarias del sur de Francia (algunas en occitano y otras en francés) y han sugerido que podrían pertenecer a una misma escuela, como se menciona también en el artículo ["Incunables de aritmética comercial anteriores a la *Summa* de Luca Pacioli"](https://www.aeca.es/comisiones/historia/esteban_florencia.pdf) de Esteban Hernández-Esteve (Universidad Autónoma de Madrid). Una de estas obras es el llamado manuscrito de Pamiers, escrito en occitano, probablemente en la década de 1430, en la ciudad de Pamiers, que se conserva en la Biblioteca Nacional de París.

La aritmética de Santcliment está compuesta de trece partes, aunque en la segunda frase del libro el propio autor anuncia que lo dividirá en quince partes. La primera parte ("De nombrar e conexer les figures") está dedicada a los números y al sistema de numeración (arábigo). La segunda parte empieza así:

> Segueixse lo aiustar e es de saber: q̄ vol dir aiustar 
>  
>   Aiustar es molts nombres metre en un lo qual solet val com tots los ajustats e no mes ne menys. e allo per explicarlos tots per una suma.

Son las mismas ideas que aparecen en el manuscrito de Pamiers, según este fragmanto reproducido en el artículo J. Sesiano, "Une arithmétique médiévale en langue provençale", *Centaurus* vol. 27, p. 26-75 (1984):

> Aiustar es diverses nombres metre en un lo qual solet valha tant com totz los autres aiustatz e non mais ni mentz.

Así mismo, Hernández-Esteve, en el artículo enlazado arriba, escribe en relación al libro *La art de arithmeticha et semblantment de ieumetria dich ho nominatus Compendion de lo abaco* (en occitano) de 
Frances Pellos, publicado en Turín en 1492:

> En el segundo capítulo, donde habla de sumar, operación que llama *aiustar*, al igual que 
>   Sanct Climent, distingue tres clases de números [...].

Existe una versión en castellano de la aritmética de Santcliment, la *Compilatio de arismetica sobre la arte mercantivol* de Franciso (sic) Sanclimente, publicada en 
Zaragoza, parece ser que hacia 1486 o 1487. Se conserva en la Biblioteca Universitaria de Cagliari (Cerdeña).  Más que una traducción, se trata de una adaptación del texto catalán (por ejemplo, contiene menos ejercicios y, en general, son de un nivel de dificultad más bajo). Pero la estructura general de la obra es parecida. Como se puede ver en el artículo de Hernández-Esteve citado anteriormente, en este libro se usa "ajustar" para indicar "sumar".

Respecto a esta elección léxica para la suma, la introducción de Malet en el libro mencionado arriba indica, en el contexto de una explicación del vocabulario que se puede considerar obsoleto, lo siguiente:

> Dos verbs que Santcliment sovinteja són particularment interessants. «Ajustar» encara té el significat d'«ajuntar» i «aplegar», però en un context matemàtic avui només connota «aproximar». És, doncs, molt lluny de «sumar», que és el significat que li dóna Santcliment de dalt a baix del llibre.

Mi traducción al castellano:

> Dos verbos que Santcliment usa frecuentemente son especialmente interesantes. «Ajustar» todavía tiene el significado de «juntar» o «reunir», pero en un contexto matemático hoy en día únicamente connota «aproximar». Está, pues, muy lejos de «sumar», que es el significado que le da Santcliment en el libro de arriba abajo.

Comment: Si bien suena más lógico el termino *ajuntar*, como puedes ver en la imagen del pdf aparece una s alargada entre la u y la t en la palabra aju*tandole. Pudo ser error de impresión, pero salvo cualquier otra respuesta, daría la tuya por válida en unos días

Comment: [Juan de Ortega](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juan_de_Ortega_(matem%C3%A1tico)) y [Miguel Jerónimo de Santa Cruz](http://dbe.rah.es/biografias/20029/miguel-jeronimo-de-santa-cruz) utilizaban "ayuntar".

Comment: https://books.google.es/books?id=RwN81o8SrysC&pg=PA74&lpg=PA74&dq=numero+que+ayuntandole&source=bl&ots=3b1Zp7b2IM&sig=ACfU3U3EVnjPXkL27Nn0TT9OowZfjn4wiQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjgktbV1trnAhUBA2MBHZN7BqsQ6AEwAHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=numero%20que%20ayuntandole&f=false

Comment: https://books.google.es/books?id=Nt4Z9d2uX68C&pg=PA35-IA1&lpg=PA35-IA1&dq=numero+que+ayuntandole&source=bl&ots=gSqXe3pFGV&sig=ACfU3U27R1XRWALFLVLffGoamKtfFacGUw&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjgktbV1trnAhUBA2MBHZN7BqsQ6AEwB3oECAMQAQ#v=snippet&q=ayunta&f=false